# Pure SQL checklist format

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I'm not sure if this is possible in SQL

I have the following tables

Below shows the list of all the food

[image]

Below shows who bought the items

[image]

Basically the user wants to display it as below

[image]

I want to use pure SQL because there is a function on my web api service to convert sqldatareader => datatable => CSV. So I don't have to manipulate the data on the api level.

Comment: Can we consider that the list of foods is fixed, or it has to be dynamically built fro the foods table (in which case you cannot use pure SQL, you need dynamic SQL)? Also, please tag your question with the database that you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: I tried adding sqlserver but it looks like it's not on the approved list and I'm not allowed to add a custom tag.

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.food) 
            FROM food c
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'select *
                from buyer
            pivot 
            (
                 COUNT(food)
                for food in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)

Comment: Thanks @Praful, is there a way to do a select within FOR food IN (select...)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with a fixed list of fruits, then a database-independent solution is conditional aggregation:

```
select
    buyer,
    max(case when food = 'apple'  then 'X' end) apple,
    max(case when food = 'banana' then 'X' end) banana,
    max(case when food = 'grapes' then 'X' end) grapes,
    max(case when food = 'lemon'  then 'X' end) lemon
from mytable
group by buyer
order by buyer
```

If the list is not fixed, then you need dynamic SQL. I would not consider that this meets the description of *pure SQL* that is described in the question.

Comment: Thanks @GMB. Is there a way to make the column flexible? I was hoping any additional food will automatically be converted to columns....

Comment: @ReydanGatchalian: a SQL query returns a *fixed* set of columns. What you ask for requires dynamic SQL, and is much more complex (and database-dependent). There are plenty of examples of such code that you can find by searching for something like "<your database> dynamic pivot".